# Copying and pasting wrong object

Tags: objects

**ISSUE:**
I am trying to copy an object from one blender file to another, how i normally do this is by copying object(CTR C)from one file, then (CTR V) in the file i want it pasted.
Now when i try doing this despite what i copy,  when i paste it, it pastes an object i didn't copy. Its an object i previously duplicated i think but i don't know how to clear this.Thanks.

picture is of the object that keeps pasting, i need this item cleared from the clipboard or something?
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think this is supposed to work. Try the "Append" in the "File" menu. You can append only what you saved in the other file. (Search for object)

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and it worked but for some unknown reason it pasted the correct object (helicopter blades) from my other blender file but it attached it to one of my cameras in my scene. Picture above.